# Как получить последнего родителя объекта?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, рекурсия, поиск

Как возможно в пример ниже зная только объект с id - 4, достать самого последнего его родителя у которого в примере id - 1

```
const items = [
    {
      title: 'Production',
      id: 1,
      subTasks: [
        {
          title: 'Production 1',
          id: 2,
          subTasks: [
            { title: 'Production 1 - 1', id: 3, subTasks: [] },
            { title: 'Production 1 - 2', id: 4, subTasks: [] },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Искать рекурсивно, запоминать где был.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения самого верхнего элемента(родителя) в дереве объектов, необходимо использовать рекурсию.

Во время поиска, будем помнить, откуда мы начали наш отсчет. При нахождении нужного ID возвращать результат.

```js
const items = [
    {
        title: 'Production',
        id: 1,
        subTasks: [
            {
                title: 'Production 1',
                id: 2,
                subTasks: [
                    { title: 'Production 1 - 1', id: 3, subTasks: [] },
                    { title: 'Production 1 - 2', id: 4, subTasks: [] },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'Production',
        id: 10,
        subTasks: [
            {
                title: 'Production 1',
                id: 20,
                subTasks: [
                    { title: 'Production 1 - 1', id: 30, subTasks: [] },
                    { title: 'Production 1 - 2', id: 40, subTasks: [] },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
]
// Бежит по всему массиву и возвращает первого найденного "Старшего" родителя
function findParent(parentList, searchItem) {
    for (let i = 0; i < parentList.length; i++) {
        if (parentList[i].id === searchItem) {
            return parentList[i].id;
        } else {
        if (parentList[i].subTasks) {
            const x = findParent(parentList[i].subTasks, searchItem);
            if (x) return parentList[i].id;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
console.log(findParent(items, 4));
console.log(findParent(items, 30));
```

```
// Если искать наличие родителя в каждом элементе индекса(для примера) 
const itemsForAll = items.map((item, index) => {
    return findParent([item], index + 4)
});
console.log(itemsForAll);
```