# Нужно перебрать многомерный массив с неизвестным количеством вложенности JS (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

На вход у меня есть такой объект:

`

```
{
    "id": 2043,
    "rowName": "444",
    "total": 2,
    "salary": 0,
    "mimExploitation": 0,
    "machineOperatorSalary": 0,
    "materials": 0,
    "mainCosts": 0,
    "supportCosts": 0,
    "equipmentCosts": 0,
    "overheads": 0,
    "estimatedProfit": 0,
    "child": [
        {
            "id": 2044,
            "rowName": "string",
            "total": 0,
            "salary": 0,
            "mimExploitation": 0,
            "machineOperatorSalary": 0,
            "materials": 0,
            "mainCosts": 0,
            "supportCosts": 0,
            "equipmentCosts": 0,
            "overheads": 0,
            "estimatedProfit": 0,
            "child": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2045,
            "rowName": "string",
            "total": 0,
            "salary": 0,
            "mimExploitation": 0,
            "machineOperatorSalary": 0,
            "materials": 0,
            "mainCosts": 0,
            "supportCosts": 0,
            "equipmentCosts": 0,
            "overheads": 0,
            "estimatedProfit": 0,
            "child": []
        }
    ]
}
```

`

В нем есть вложенность (child). У этой вложенности может быть еще вложенность. Мне нужно создать функцию, для его обработки.

Мой объект перебирался map функцией.

```
list.map((el, i) => {

      return (
        ... (Вывод значений объекта)
      );
    });
```

Попробовал map, но в ней нельзя использовать работать с вложенностью

Comment: Делайте функцию с рекурсией и работайте с этой функцией. Что такое рекурсия - в интрнете информации вагон

Comment: По ссылке пример [использования рекурсии в объекте с неизвестным количеством вложений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1449714/1450917#1450917). Структура данных там похожа на вашу