# Как найти ключ объекта, зная только внутренний ключ?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть объект с большим количеством ключей, у всех этих ключей может быть неограниченная вложенность, как найти ключ первой вложенности зная только название вложенного ключа?

```
const test = {
  x: {
     x1: 1,
     x2: {
       x3: 2
     }
  },
  y: {
     y1: 1,
     y2: {
       y3: 2
     },
  }
}
```

Как найти x, если есть только название внутреннего ключа?

Comment: Посмотрите, как пример [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1449714/). Там делалось то же самое, только бежали не по объекту, а по массиву объектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуемся встроенным методом объекта **Object.entries** для преобразования объекта к массиву вида `[ [ключ, значение], [ключ2, значение2] ]`

Далее будем рекурсивно обходить все ключи и сравнивать, запоминая первый.
Если ничего не найдем, вернется **false**

```js
const test = {
    x: {
        x1: 1,
        x2: {
            x3: 2
        }
    },
    y: {
        y1: 1,
        y2: {
            y3: 2
        },
    }
}

function objFind(array, find, top) {
    const arr = Object.entries(array);
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i][0] === find) return top ? top : arr[i][0];
        const res = objFind(arr[i][1], find, !top ? arr[i][0] : top);
        if (res) return res;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log('Find x3:', objFind(test, 'x3'));
console.log('Find y2:', objFind(test, 'y2'));
console.log('Find z4:', objFind(test, 'z4'));
```